# Replacing value in python numpy masked array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the foll. numpy masked array:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = -9999.0)
```

I want to replace all the -9999.0 in this masked array with 0.0, but the foll. does not work:

```
arr.data[arr == -9999.0] = 0.0
```

The resulting `arr` still has all the -9999.0 in it. How do I fix it?

--EDIT:

This is what arr.data looks like:

```
array([[-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       ..., 
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999., ..., -9999., -9999., -9999.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Are you sure it has `-9999.0` in it, and not some other floats very close to `-9999.0`?

Comment: thanks @wim, I am absolutely sure it is -9999.0

Comment: @wim, edited question to show what `arr.data` looks like

Comment: Do you also want to change the mask?  `arr.filled(0)` might be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mask is on where the `arr.mask` has value True.

All those values `-9999.` values are masked.

If you want it to apply to the masked values aswell, instead of using this:

```
arr.data[arr == -9999.0] = 0.0
```

It should be this:

```
arr.data[arr.data == -9999.0] = 0.0
```

**Note:**  Be careful with float equality comparisons like this.  Usually you want comparison within a tolerance, instead of direct equality.  See [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) to read more details about that.